# How to find diameter of image using matlab?

Tags: matlab, feature-extraction

I have images of a leaf,now I want to find the diameter of the leaf using matlab, for feature extraction

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS4Rx.jpg)

An help would be appreciated.

Comment: The diameter of what? What have you tried? What technology do you use to detect the features?

Comment: as a starting point have a look at `regionprops` that will give you some information about your region. http://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html

Answer (score 0):

In your image you want scan the pixels top to bottom and bottom to top,and get the first pixel values,using this pixels you can get diameter.The same method using in left to right and right to left manner.then you find the maximum value as your diameter.

This is code for mark first pixels,try this.

`%Mark horizontal pixel`
`[row1, column1] = find(thinImg, 1, 'last');`
`hold on;`
`plot(column1, row1, 'yX', 'MarkerSize', 15);`

`%Mark vertical pixel`
`[row2, column2] = find(thinImg, 1, 'first');`
`hold on;`
`plot(row2, column2, 'yX', 'MarkerSize', 15);`